# how to sign in child on parent/child create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following the RoR Tutorial for my application.  My set up is slightly different and I am so new to rails I can't figure out how to tweek the code.  In the tutorial you create Users and sign them in.  In my app I am creating a Company that has many Users.  All that works.  However, I want to sign the User in (not the company) when I create a new Company/User pair.  The initial create is through the Companies_Controller, while the sign_in code in the tutorial runs through the Users_Controller.

When I log in as an existing User it works, but the initial create never hits the Users_Controller so it doesn't sign in.

I tried adding:

> sign_in @company.users

to the create method of the Companies_Controller

In the SesionsHelper the sign_in method looks like this:

> def sign_in(user)
>       cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
>       self.current_user = user
>     end

I get the error:

Failure/Error: post :create, :company => @attr

> ```
> NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
>  # ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:4:in `sign_in'
>  # ./app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:15:in `create'
> ```

I'm not clear how to pass the user info that I just collected in the Company create form to the method in the SessionsHelper.  Or do I need to write a second set of sign_in methods for the initial creation?  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Well, for starters: `@company.users` will be a list of users, while your helper function is expecting a single user object

Comment: Thanks, I added 
`@user = User.new(params[:user])
sign_in @user`
to the Companies_controller and now the company and user will create.  I am still having issues, but they are something else now.